# Как изменить шаг регулировки с одного на 10?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var $numberInput = $(".bid_inp");
var $plusButton = $(".bid_plus");
var $minusButton = $(".bid_minus");

$numberInput.val("{{$lot->cur_bid}}");

$plusButton.on('click', function() {
  $numberInput[0].value++;
});
$minusButton.on('click', function() {
  if ($numberInput.val() > 1) {
    $numberInput[0].value--;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bid_blocks text-center mt10">
  <div class="bid_col btn-g">
    <span class="bid_minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bid_col">
    <input type="number" name="" disabled class="bid_inp">
  </div>
  <div class="bid_col btn-g">
    <span class="bid_plus">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $numberInput[0].value += 10? Ну и на -=10

Comment: Пробовал, так добавляет за числом, а мне нужно чтобы суммировал

Comment: Используйте унарный "+".
$numberInput[0].value = +$numberInput[0].value +10.

https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $numberInput = $(".bid_inp:first");
var $plusButton = $(".bid_plus");
var $minusButton = $(".bid_minus");
let step = 10;


$numberInput.val(0);

$plusButton.on('click', function() {
    $numberInput.val(+$numberInput.val()+step);
});
$minusButton.on('click', function() {
  if ($numberInput.val() >= step) {
    $numberInput.val(+$numberInput.val()-step);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bid_blocks text-center mt10">
  <div class="bid_col btn-g">
    <span class="bid_minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bid_col">
    <input type="number" name="" disabled class="bid_inp">
  </div>
  <div class="bid_col btn-g">
    <span class="bid_plus">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
```